# Reading binary file from URLConnection

Tags: java, http, download, urlconnection

I'm trying to read a binary file from a URLConnection. When I test it with a text file it seems to work fine but for binary files it doesn't. I'm using the following mime-type on the server when the file is send out:

```
application/octet-stream
```

But so far nothing seems to work. This is the code that I use to receive the file:

```
file = File.createTempFile( "tempfile", ".bin");
file.deleteOnExit();

URL url = new URL( "http://somedomain.com/image.gif" );

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream() ) );

Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream( file ) );

int c;

while( ( c = input.read() ) != -1 ) {

   writer.write( (char)c );
}

writer.close();

input.close();
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is how I do it,

```
input = connection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int n;

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( file );
while ((n = input.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{
    output.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
output.close();
```

Comment: The `n > 0` test is unnecessary.  According to the javadocs, the only case where zero can be returned is when `buffer.length` is zero.

Comment: ... and in any case a zero length write is harmless.

Answer (score 15):

If you are trying to read a binary stream, you should NOT wrap the `InputStream` in a `Reader` of any kind.  Read the data into a byte array buffer using the `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` method.  Then write from the buffer to a `FileOutputStream`.

The way you are currently reading/writing the file will convert it into "characters" and back to bytes using your platform's default character encoding.  This is liable to mangle binary data.

(There is a charset (LATIN-1) that provides a 1-to-1 lossless mapping between bytes and a subset of the `char` value-space.  However this is a bad idea even when the mapping works.  You will be translating / copying the binary data from `byte[]` to `char[]` and back again ... which achieves nothing in this context.)

Comment: Or you can try wrapping up your InputStream into BufferedInputStream.

Comment: @bhups - that is true, but it will only help if you are going to do lots of small reads.  If you exclusively do large block reads, a BufferedInputStream will actually reduce throughput a bit.

Comment: This is correct; `InputStreamReader` will transform byte data to UTF-16 character data (in this case, using the default platform encoding, which is a bad idea even for text/plain). A Java char is not an octet as it is in some other languages.

Comment: @StephenC, regarding your last (+1 useful) comment - What buffer-size would still be considered as causing "lots of small reads" (by your definition)?
In other words, how small "should" the `byte[]` read-buffer be, to justify usage of `BufferedInputStream`?

Comment: I can't give you an exact number.  It depends on the relative costs of a syscall, the sizes of the buffer and the `byte[]`, and so on.  But my real point is to not *assume* that using a buffered stream always makes things faster.